# How do I make an extruder move up and down while Scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am making a website with an extruder on the left (a box you click that opens up new content). You can see the site here: [SITE](https://www.retirementautopilot.com/capitalfinancial/)

My problem is, the extruder on the left stays where it is when I scroll up and down. In my source code, on line 15, you will see this code commented out:

```
<!--<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>-->
```

That code is taken straight from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js, but saved locally so I can edit it. When that file is not commented out, the extruder scrolls perfectly when I move up and down the page, but it causes my dropdown navigation (when you hover over "About" and "Services") to stop working.

So, my question is, how can I get the extruder to function properly, without it messing up my dropdown navigation?

Comment: Is there anything I can do?

Comment: ok. lets you menu will work, keep your <!--<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>-->. And what now dont working???

Comment: You want that extruderLeft scrol and menu working at the same time??eh?

Comment: Exactly. I want them both to work at the same time.